# Failed to resolve no.nordicsemi.android.support.v18:scanner

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio, gradle

I want to use **scanner** of `no.nordicsemi.android.support.v18`,but when I build the project,such error occurred:

```
Failed to resolve no.nordicsemi.android.support.v18:scanner
```

Here is my **build.gradle in app module:**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.8.0'
    compile 'no.nordicsemi.android.support.v18:scanner:0.1.1'
    compile project(':common')
}
```

And my **build.gradle in project:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I have search the dependency and found it's in maven repository,but I can't sync it to local while others like `com.google.android.support:wearable:1.3.0` did well,who can tell me why this error occurred and how can I solve this,thanks.

Comment: Did you have a proxy?

Comment: Yes,I'm using proxy.

Comment: It seems that you haven't set the proxy in AS configuration.

Comment: I have enabled it in AS,and others dependency like support-v4 can be sync normallly.

Comment: the support libraries aren't in jcenter. They are on a local maven on you machine.

Comment: I have found it in maven repository.

Comment: when i use `compile` then its working fine but when i use `implementation` then its send me this error. do you have any solution for that

Answer (score 0):

Your app's minSdkVersion is probably below 18. Android-Scanner-Compat-Library (no.nordicsemi.android.support.v18:scanner:0.1.1') has a minimum SDK version of 18 so you can only use it on projects with minSdkVersion of 18+

Comment: Thanks your answer,but I have clarified that minSdkVersion=18.